# scala play : aggregate conf files for tests

Tags: scala, playframework

My application is composed of two projects : `root` and `commons`. `root` depends on `commons`. My `build.sbt` is made so that both main and test are aggregated :

```
lazy val commons = RootProject(file("../commons"))

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .aggregate(commons)
  .dependsOn(commons % "test->test;compile->compile")
```

The problem is, when I run `commons` tests from `root`, they don't inherit conf defined in `root` `application.conf`. Example :

```
class EventSourceTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with ScalaFutures {

  val env: Environment = play.api.Environment.simple()
  val configuration: Configuration = Configuration.load(env) // doesn't contain root conf
  // [...]
}
```

How do I make `commons` tests to use configurations defined from `application.conf` in `root` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to solve a problem you should not have. If commons and root are 2 different projects (even if they are sub-project a single sbt project), your tests should not cross project boundaries.

If you are thinking about integration level tests, the code from *commons* that is called from *root* should be responsible for loading the configuration it relies on.

Comment: Thansks, that make sense. How to load the configuration it relies on ?

Comment: If your configuration file is in the default location:

_import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory_
_Config conf = ConfigFactory.load()_

For more exotic things, you can find explanations and examples there: [link](https://github.com/typesafehub/config)

Answer (score 0):

When you run your sbt, you have the option to specify which conf file to load and you can come up with a custom logic that reads this config and loads the corresponding conf file.

As a starter, here is what you could do:

```
Option(System.getProperty("config.file")) match {
 case Some(path) => ConfigFactory.parse(...=)

 ...
}
```

And you call your tests like

```
sbt -Dconfig.file=/path/to/config/file test
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer, but this is not the answer I was looking for ^^

Comment: Yes, not a problem! I did not read your question throughly! It was my fault!